# Regex captured groups with positive lookbehind (python)

Tags: python, regex

How is it possible to combine a captured group with positive lookbehinds?

I want to match the following examples:

```
DS
DS,x=y
Some DS,key=value
Some DS test,key=value&key2=value2
Some DS test,key=value&key2=value2|key3=value3
```

I came up with the following regex for matching everything but the comma:

```
^(?P<ds_title>[\w \|\-\=\&æøåÆØÅ]+)(?P<filters>[\w \|\-\=\&æøåÆØÅ]+)?$
```

I've figured out, that the regex I would need to insert is:

```
(?<=\,)
```

But I cannot figure out where to insert it. No matter where I insert it, it seems to break. Does anyone know how this can be done correctly?

Comment: would you mind to post one or two lines with text, and the matchings you want

Comment: What is DS? Currently your question is quite vague, and unanswerable. Please elaborate a little more probably with some working examples.

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear. The regex already finds the correct characters - "Some DS" is just some random text. What I need is to implement the optional comma between the two existing groups.

Comment: You need to use `^(?P<ds_title>[\w \|\-\=\&æøåÆØÅ]+)(?:,(?P<filters>[\w \|\-\=\&æøåÆØÅ,]+))?$`

Comment: EPIC, thanks a lot! I'm not a very experienced stack overflow user, but if you make an answer I can mark it as correct, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you overthinking this?

```
^(?P<ds_title>[^,]+)(?:,(?P<filters>.+))?$
```

Why not just allow any string, rather than limiting it to your list?

---

In fact, why use a regex at all?

```
parts = data.split(',', 2)
if len(parts) == 1:
    title, = parts
else:
    title, filters = parts
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP wants, but the OP's regex can do some preliminary validation on the input.